# How to create a gantt chart using .net report viewer?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, report

I am using visual studio 2010 to create a VB reporting website. I found a blog which tells me how to use range bar chart to create a gantt chart. But I got some problems with how to group the bars(tasks) on task names.

My database structrue is shown below:

```
 Taskname      StartTime           EndTime
 task1         2012-03-01 8:00     2012-03-01 10:00
 task2         2012-03-01 9:00     2012-03-01 14:00
 task1         2012-03-01 17:00    2012-03-01 18:00
 task2         2012-03-03 18:00    2012-03-03 19:30
```

I would like use the above data to generate a gantt chart like this:

```
       task1                                           task1
       -----                                           ---
             task 2                                                    task 2
             -------------------------                                 -------
```

In visual studio's report designer, I first added a range bar chart. Then dropped the taskname filed to the category fileds. So my understanding is the range bars will be grouped by task name. For the data fields, I dropped starttime(start value) and endtime(top value). I also set the 'draw side by side' property to false. But when I run my website, I could only see one task for each task type in the gantt chart( one task1 and one task 2) . It didn't show me all the tasks. So my incorrect result is shown below:

```
     task1
     ------
             task 2
             -------------------------
```

No matter how many records are there in my database, the gantt chart only shows the first record for each task type. Does anyone know why this could happen? I wasted lot of time on this now:(. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a series group to your graph - otherwise, it tries to draw one line per value field per category group. (By default, the low and high values should have been generated as aggregates; you probably had to amend them to be the field values, with the result that the graph plots the *first* low and high values for each category group.)

If you add StartTime to your graph as a series group, you should find that the values will be plotted correctly.